# Checkbox style not toggled correctly when action set on parent, updated data is sent from parent to child

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, ember.js

I have a card component with a checkbox, to which the checked status is passed from the parent.
The checkbox is hidden and the label is styled to look like a checkbox. The whole card containing the checkbox has the action handler. When I click the checkbox label or the card directly it toggles correctly, but when using Space, the action is fired correctly but the checkbox is not toggled. I see that the checked property is not set in DOM for the hidden checkbox, hence the style for checked checkbox is not rendered. I tried to make checked a computed property on the card component to force a re-render when the checked value is updated, but no luck.

```
<!-- parent -->
{{#each userList as |user|}}
<li {{action "selectCard" user}}>
  {{member-card
     name=user.name
     checkboxId=user.checkboxId
     checked=user.checked
  }}
</li>
<!-- child -->
<div>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id={{checkboxId}}
    checked={{checked}}
  />
  <label for={{checkboxId}} class="result-card__name-label">
   {{name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

On inspecting I found that the checked DOM property is not getting set correctly. When I tried:

```
<!-- child -->
{{#if checked}}
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id={{checkboxId}}
    checked
  />
{{else}}
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id={{checkboxId}} />
{{/if}}
```

this seems to give the result I want.
One solution that works is if I set the same action handler on the checkbox label as well, and prevent the event from bubbling when it is clicked. But this doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Wanted to understand that why checkbox not getting re-rendered correctly.

I would suppose that since the checked property is updated when I click on the card (I verified this using ember inspector) I would assume that checked property would be check on the checkbox. But for some reason this isn't how it is working.
I ended but using prevent default on the label, to stop the propagation of event from it to checkbox to stop it from firing the event again.

Ember version: 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show, should work. Here's a Twiddle demonstrating it: https://ember-twiddle.com/0631193dc09a3646ca9e9a1efe351607?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

Your problem likely lies elsewhere.

How are you setting the `checked` property on the `user` object? Is `user` an instance of `EmberObject` or a POJO?

If it's a POJO and you're doing `user.checked = true`, the template won't update. There's no way for Ember to know that the property has changed.

Make it an instance of `EmberObject` and use `user.set()` to set it.

Or, if you're on Ember Octane (recommended), `user` can be an instance of a simple class, and you can use the `@tracked` decorator on the `checked` class property. Then you can use `user.checked = true` to change the checkbox state.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think the `user` is a simple object. I changed the code. By putting all the elements inside the label and setting the click on the checkbox input. This worked.This is also legal according to the W3C guideline. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thx for accepting the answer! Don't forget to upvote too.